# how to display checkbox when input number more than (30) javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a form for reservation and I want when the visitor input more than $30 in (input tag price) display the hotel star(1) and star(2) as a checkbox, more than $60 display the hotel star(3) as a checkbox, more than $100 display the hotel star(4) and star(5) as a checkbox. I want it in JavaScript.

```js
function gotowhatsapp() {

  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var filter = document.getElementById("filter").value;
  var url = "https://wa.me/MY NUMBER?text="

    +
    "السعر المطلوب :  " + price + "%0a" +
    "نجوم الفندق :  " + filter + "%0a"

  window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="سعر الليلة" value="" required="" min="5" max="500" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group startdiv">
    <p class="starinputp"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" onclick="myFunction()" id="starinput" value="نجمة واحدة" />&nbsp;نجمة واحدة<br></p>
    <p class="starinputp"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" onclick="myFunction()" id="starinput" value="نجمتان" />&nbsp;نجمتان<br></p>
    <p class="starinputp"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" onclick="myFunction()" id="starinput" value="3 نجوم" />&nbsp;3 نجوم<br></p>
    <p class="starinputp"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" onclick="myFunction()" id="starinput" value="4 نجوم" />&nbsp;4 نجوم<br></p>
    <p class="starinputp"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" onclick="myFunction()" id="starinput" value="5 نجوم" />&nbsp;5 نجوم<br></p>

    <input type="text" id="filter" size="50" style="display: none;">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="gotowhatsapp()" value="ارسال" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Protips: 1) IDs _must_ be unique. It's invalid HTML to repeat them. 2) Don't use paragraphs as input layout mechanisms. That's not their purpose. 3) consider using a single event listener instead of repeated inline function calls (onclick attributes). 4) Don't include commented-out code or other distractions in an SO post. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].